# How to check if a database is set up in settings.php?

Tags: 8, configuration

I am creating a module for Drupal 8. One of the requirements is that you first add a new database in [settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/databases/8.x). On the admin page, I want to check if the user did this step and show a warning if he didn't. I tried this:

```
global $databases;
```

But doing a var_dump shows nothing.

How do I access the databases variable so I can check if the database is setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

global $databases has been removed in favor of the preexisting static connection info management methods on the Database class.

Drupal 7

```
global $databases;
// Check whether we have a default connection.
$has_connection = !empty($databases['default']['default']);
```

Drupal 8

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
$has_connection = (bool) Database::getConnectionInfo('default');
```

More links

https://www.drupal.org/node/2176621

https://www.drupal.org/node/1951216

Comment: do not force to bool.`$has_connection = Database::getConnectionInfo('default');
dpm($has_connection);`